# razor pages - how to populate form fields from update model

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

The 'itemId' is transferred to the Update Page, however, form fields are empty. This is my first try to Update the model in Razor Pages. Any help is appreciated.

```
   [BindProperty]
    public MenuItemViewModel MenuItem { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int itemId)
    {
        var the_item = _menuItemService.GetById(itemId);
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var the_item = MenuItem.ToDomainModel();
            _menuItemService.Update(the_item);

        }
        return Page();
    }
```

cshtml:

```
<div class="container">
    <form asp-page="UpdateMenuItem" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.ImageUrl">Image:</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.ImageUrl" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter image" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.ImageUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.">Description:</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter description" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Price">Price:</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public IActionResult OnGet(int itemId)
    {
        MenuItem  = _menuItemService.GetById(itemId);
        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the 'asp-for' tag too many times and it creates an ambiguity when the Post method tries to find the model:

```
<label asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

remove asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" from the label and span. Only use it for the input fields like so:

```
      <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Enter name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.MenuItem.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Only do this for the actual models you are binding. Do not use them for labels.
Let me know if that works out for you.